# Query com condições no SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Seguem as tabelas abaixo com minha dúvida

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou com um problema, em que fazer um filtro em que preciso pegar as postagens que tenham a coluna postagem_pai da tabela postagem com valor diferente de 0, e também preciso verificar se o id_autor da postagem é igual ao id_autor da postagem que vem na coluna postagem_pai. É nesse segundo item que estou me embolando. Eu montei a minha query, mas não sei se a mesma está 100%. Segue abaixo:

```
SELECT p.id_postagem, p.titulo, a.nome
FROM postagem p JOIN autor a
ON p.id_autor = a.id_autor
WHERE postagem_pai <> 0
AND C.id_autor = (SELECT id_autor FROM postagem where id_postagem = c.postagem_pai AND id_autor = u.id_autor)
```

Caso a mesma não esteja correta, como devo fazer essas condições?

**OBS.: Estou usando o SQL SERVER**

Comment: Não estou vendo a necessidade dessa ultima linha "AND C.id_autor ...". Pois voce ja esta fazendo o join com essas duas tabelas.

Comment: entendi, minha necessidade para ficar até mais claro, era nesse exemplo, trazer as postagens com exceção da 50228

Comment: DiChrist acho que você quis dizer que deseja trazer todas as postagem exceto a de id_postagem=50225 certo? Se não você estará trazendo a postagem com o valor da coluna postagem_pai=0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pensando em uma abordagem um pouco a frente, pensei que talvez você queira trabalhar com uma estrutura que permita que você tenha "netos" de suas postagens. Pra isso fiz o seguinte `script` de inserção:

```
CREATE TABLE autor(
  id_autor INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  nome     VARCHAR(100)
);
go

CREATE TABLE postagem(
  id_postagem  INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  titulo       VARCHAR(100),
  id_autor     INT,
  postagem_pai INT,
  CONSTRAINT fk_postagem_autor FOREIGN KEY (id_autor) REFERENCES autor (id_autor),
  CONSTRAINT fk_postagem_postagem FOREIGN KEY (postagem_pai) REFERENCES postagem (id_postagem)
);
go

-- Inserções
DECLARE @id_autor     INT,
        @postagem_pai INT;

-- Insere os autores
INSERT INTO autor(nome)
VALUES('Autor01');

SET @id_autor = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT INTO autor(nome)
VALUES('Autor02');

-- Insere o pai
INSERT INTO postagem(titulo, id_autor)
VALUES('post_pai', @id_autor);

SET @postagem_pai = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

-- Insere filhos
INSERT INTO postagem(titulo, id_autor, postagem_pai)
VALUES('post_filho1', @id_autor, @postagem_pai),
      ('post_filho2', @id_autor, @postagem_pai),
      ('post_filho3', @id_autor, @postagem_pai);

SET @postagem_pai = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

-- Insere netos
INSERT INTO postagem(titulo, id_autor, postagem_pai)
VALUES('post_neto3.1', @id_autor, @postagem_pai)
go
```

Que produz o seguinte resultado:

**Tabela autor**

[image: Tabela autor]

**Tabela postagem**

[image: Tabela postagem]

**Utilizando WITH**

Assim para produzir a seleção de todas as postagens utilizei a expressão `WITH` do `SQL Server`.

> [`WITH common_table_expression`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> Especifica um conjunto de resultados nomeado temporário, conhecido como uma CTE (expressão de tabela comum). Ela é derivada de uma consulta simples e definida no escopo de execução de uma única instrução SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ou DELETE. Esta cláusula também pode ser usada em uma instrução CREATE VIEW como parte da instrução SELECT que a define. Uma expressão de tabela comum pode incluir referências a si mesma. É o que chamamos de expressão de tabela comum recursiva.

```
WITH conjunto AS(
  -- Aqui vai a seleção do registro base que você desejado (Também chamado de "archor")
  SELECT pai.*,
         1 AS nivel
    FROM postagem pai
   -- Aqui você insere o parâmetro que dirá qual postagem é a raiz
   WHERE pai.id_postagem = 1
  UNION ALL
  -- Note que abaixo a select tem um union na declaração do "WITH"
  SELECT filho.*,
         pai.nivel + 1 AS nivel
    FROM postagem filho
         -- Aqui se aplica a recursão
         INNER JOIN conjunto pai ON pai.id_postagem = filho.postagem_pai
)
SELECT conj.*
  FROM conjunto conj
```

**RESULTADO:**

[image: Resultado WITH]

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar um "Self Join" para filtrar as postagens onde o autor do post é igual ao autor do post pai:

```
SELECT 
   pFilho.id_postagem, pFilho.titulo, a.nome
FROM
   postagem pFilho
   INNER JOIN postagem pPai
      ON pFilho.postagem_pai = pPai.id_postagem
      AND pFilho.id_autor = pPai.id_autor
   INNER JOIN autor a
      ON pFilho.id_autor = a.id_autor
WHERE
   pFilho.postagem_pai <> 0
```

Esta última condição é redundante, já que provavelmente não existe postagem com `id_postagem` zerada.

Answer (score 1):

Penso que se utilizares o left join para relacionar as duas tabelas ficará mais simples:

```
SELECT p.id_postagem, p.titulo, a.nome
FROM postagem p 
LEFT JOIN autor a
  ON p.id_autor = a.id_autor
WHERE postagem_pai <> 0
  AND p.id_autor = p.postagem_pai
```